# Playing YouTube videos in Livecode

Tags: browser, youtube, livecode

I am trying to use a Browser instance to play YouTube video using EMBED code.

[You can find my sample project here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bznu7JgRtB5CR2R6bElnMVNPeHc/view?usp=sharing).

The video player loads OK, but when I click play, the audio comes through, but the image remains black.

Can anyone suggest what is going wrong? ( I'd ideally, eventually like this to work on mobile too ). Code provided below.

```
########### LIVECODE
global sBrowserId

on mouseUp
  repeat for each item theItem in revBrowserInstances()
      revBrowserClose theItem
   end repeat

   altBrowserOn

end mouseUp

on altBrowserOn
   put empty into tAddress
   put field "soundcloud" into PAGINAHTML
   -- We pass the windowId of the stack to revBrowser 
   put the windowid of this stack into tWinID
   -- Open the browser, using the windowId and initial url
   put revBrowserOpen(tWinID,tAddress) into sBrowserId
   revBrowserSet sBrowserId, "htmltext", PAGINAHTML

   if sBrowserId is not an integer then
      answer "Error opening browser: " & sBrowserId
      exit altBrowserOn
   end if

   -- Set some basic properties for the browser
   revBrowserSet sBrowserId, "showborder","true"
   revBrowserSet sBrowserId, "scrollbars","false"
   revBrowserSet sBrowserId, "useragent", "Mozilla/5.0 ;iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X; AppleWebKit/537.51.2 ;KHTML, like Gecko; Version/7.0 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53"
   put the rect of field "soundcloud" of this card into tRectImage
   revBrowserSet sBrowserId, "rect", tRectImage

end altBrowserOn

on altBrowserOff
   if sBrowserId is  an integer then
      revBrowserClose sBrowserId
   end if
end altBrowserOff

####### END LIVECODE


####### EMBED CODE

<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/56G8tuyez5s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>

########## END EMBED CODE
```

Comment: Found it. Mimicking my Chrome browser user agent did it... 

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36

Comment: SORRY! No that hasn't fixed it. Just has on one video.

Comment: Very sorry once again. I copied the code and objects into a new stack and it just works. I suspect memory got messed up at some point. It now plays both YouTube and Soundcloud embed code.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues with the LC Browser is that it does not come with the h264 codec installed. Some of YouTube's videos are encoded using this codec, the same with Vimeo.  Only way around is to build your own CEF.